# Not able to apply custom style on column headings inside f:facet

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I am a beginner in richfaces and I am facing issue in applying custom style to column headings which is defined in `f:facet`. Iam using JSF-2 and Richfaces-4.
My code is as below:

```
<rich:dataTable  value="#{techworkdetails.workList}"  var="tech"   
    cellpadding="5"  style="width:100%" headerClass="myHeader">

   <f:facet name="header" >
    <rich:columnGroup > 
        <rich:column >Name</rich:column>
        <rich:column >Order#</rich:column>
        <rich:column >Order Date</rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet> 

<rich:collapsibleSubTable value="#{tech.workDetails}"  
    var="details" rowKeyVar="rowKey" >
    <rich:column rowspan="#{tech.workDetails.size()}" rendered="#{rowKey eq 0}">
        #{tech.name}
    </rich:column >
    <rich:column  styleClass="myHeader">
        #{details.orderNo}
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
         #{details.orderDate}
    </rich:column>

</rich:collapsibleSubTable>
```

I have included the stylesheet using

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="pagestyle.css" library="css" />
```

inside `h:body`.

"myHeader" style is defined as:

```
.myHeader{
    background-color : yellow;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Problem is that even if I use headerClass for my dataTable, my style is not getting reflected; insted the default style of the heading is rendered. But custom style for the data column is rendered. i.e, my style is getting applied for data in *details.OrderNo*  column as given.
I also tried using styleClass and style for the header columns individually as below, but no luck :(

```
<f:facet name="header" >
    <rich:columnGroup > 
       <rich:column styleClass="myHeader">Name</rich:column>
      <rich:column styleClass="myHeader">Order#</rich:column>
          <rich:column styleClass="myHeader">Order Date</rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>
```

Is it that we cannot apply style for rich:column inside f:facet ? 
Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your CSS is added to the page before Richfaces add their own and so the former gets overwritten. To prevent the overwriting you need to add `!important` to your CSS attributes.

In your case that would be:

```
.myHeader{
    background-color : yellow !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

this way the browser will keep the important styles.